# C Drive is full

Tags: hard-drive

I recently noticed that my "C" drive is 97% (97 GB) full. There are no junk files on it because I run ccleaner everyday.  When I search "C" for files by size there are only 6 files larger than 100 MB. My pictures, videos and documents were moved to my D drive a few months back.

How can I find what is taking up so much space and what can I do about it?

Comment: Use any of the many tools that report drive usage.

Comment: What Operating system are you running.  I assume Windows but Windows 7, 8, 10?

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution is [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info) ([WinDirStat.info installer](http://windirstat.info/wds_current_setup.exe)).  You may specify a hard drive, local folder, or remote folder.  It can take a while to fully analyze a drive.  In the meantime, you can see what it figured out so far.  Once it fully analyzes whatever it is looking at, it will use up some of the lower part of the window, drawing what it calls a "treemap".  There, you can often visually see large files instantly.  Also, in the upper-right corner, it will show extensions, sorted by what uses the most space.  Those are the neatest aspects of the program.  Being able to delete files, launch explorer windows, and sending E-Mail reports are some other features.

In the future, if you ever dabble with Unix, there is a similar program called KDirStat with most of the same features.  (In fact, WinDirStat was designed to act like KDirStat.)

That is the best solution I've encountered.  If you don't have enough space to install even a small program like that, you can right-click a folder in Windows Explorer, and choose properties, to find out the size of the individual folder.

Answer (score -1):

I have found overdisk to be very helpful

http://www.snapfiles.com/get/overdisk.html

It shows amount of used space as a sort of pie chat and it's light weight

If you can extract the ece file from it's installer it can work as a standalone program without having to install it

Answer (score -2):

Please use the below software

https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/

It will quickly Scan Directory Sizes and Find Space usage.

[Download link](http://www.jamsoft.net/treesize_free/TreeSizeFreeSetup.exe)

Comment: I am running Windows 10, 64 Bit.  Acer PC with 3 drives.

Comment: Yes. The software is compatible with Windows 10, 64 bit

Comment: why is this down voted?